# 'Real' type fields lose scale in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, arcgis-10.5

I have some data in SQL Server 2016 which contains a field type of REAL, and I have no control over changing the underlying schema.  This is not in an Enterprise Geodatabase, but is a simple table containing a geometry field.

This is how it looks via SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

We can see this appears similar to a float:

[image: Adding the data into ArcMap/ArcGIS Pr]o via a Query Layer, it looks like this:
Flows through as a float but I have lost the [scale](http://images.slideplayer.com/28/9303425/slides/slide_9.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Looking at the help - [SQL Server data types supported in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/data-types-sqlserver.htm) – suggests REAL field type is supported for view only (which is what I need).

[image]

However, I can't see where I can change any settings to ensure the full scale flows through.

Hoping this might be an easy one to solve and something basic I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Change the query layer to use a CAST in the SELECT statement, to CAST the real fields to floats.

SELECT TOP (1000) [uniqueID], CAST(TrafficDensity AS numeric(10,5)) AS TrafficDensity,[geomColumn] FROM [database].[dbo].[TrafficDensity]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZe]gs.png